# Problems using python 3.7 on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I'm doing a project in nodejs but I also use python to streamline some things, but when trying to deploy with python 3.7.9 as indicated in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes
but when the deploy starts this error jumps I already have the requirements.txt and the runtime.txt

```coffee
-----> Python app detected
 !     Requested runtime (﻿python-3.7.9) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Per the docs on [specifying a Python version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes), is your runtime.txt casing correct? And is your requirements.txt file complete, e.g. has all dependencies and is frozen to the correct versions?

Comment: @gallen If the dependencies are frozen well and the runtime.txt is fine

Comment: From the [Support page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#checking-the-python-buildpack-version) -- If you are seeing “Requested runtime is not available for this stack” errors using one of the versions above, check that your app is using the latest version of the Python buildpack.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of the buildpack and I really don't know why this error is appearing

Comment: @Esponjosin, what is the encoding of your `runtime.txt` file? Most decent text editors can show you that, or you can try running `file runtime.txt` on Linux or macOS. If it isn't already utf-8, try saving in that encoding, committing, and then redeploying.

Comment: @Chris I always save the files in utf-8 and try modifying the encoding